# Formatting XML from Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to create XML:

```
 class Output
  require 'nokogiri'

  def self.xml
    data = IncomingData.all
    builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
      xml.root {
        data.each do |o|
          xml.id {
            xml.account_id_    o.account_id
            xml.date_          o.date
            xml.account_type  o.account_type
            xml.activity      o.activity
            xml.position      o.position
            xml.security      o.security
          }

        end
      }
    end
    builder.to_xml
  end
end
```

This is my controller action:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.xml { render xml: Output.xml }
end
```

which works nicely: [image]

But I need to output it with indentation like:

```
account_id
  date
   account_type
```

How I can do it?

`ruby -v` returns:

```
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

`nokogiri --version` returns:

```
# Nokogiri (1.6.7)
```

Comment: The requested output is not XML? Are you wanting it to be XML or just the string with indentation?

Comment: @Yule i want xml with indentation

Comment: Builder should output XML with indentation by default.  The .to_xml method on the @builder object will do this for you.

Comment: @cherrysoft i did  '@builder.to_xml' but not works

Comment: Can you detail what versions of Ruby and Nokogiri library?

Comment: try .to_xml(:indent => 2, :encoding => 'UTF-8')

Comment: @cherrysoft updated issue

Comment: Are you saving the XML to a file and opening or printing to screen?  Maybe try passing the options = {:indent => 2} to the builder constructor.

Comment: its screenshot,where i should add {:indent => 2} @cherrysoft

Comment: i did builder.to_xml(:indent => 2) no luck

Comment: If it is the screenshot then your XML is indented correctly!!!

Comment: What is the exact output that you want? The example you've given does not contain any XML tags, nor does it contain any values?

Comment: The example output *IS* indented correctly for XML. The desired output indentation isn't XML, isn't standard or correct indentation. As a result we have no idea what you're asking for, and, because it's not standard, it's not possible directly from Nokogiri. Please add a LOT more description and detail, including why you think the desired output is correct XML.

Answer (score 0):

Just create valid hash, and add to him .to_xml method

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers need more than a single line; Explain why it works, and show an example of how to do it. As is this is more of a comment.